# Why does the error "vfprintf_chk.c: No such file or directory" occur?

Tags: c++, c

The code is as follows:

```
int outlog_printf(size_t level, const char* format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    int ret = 0;
    // We are going to print this to the screen
    if (verbose_level >= level) {
        va_start(args, format);
        ret = vfprintf(stdout, format, args);
        fflush(stdout);
        va_end(args);
    }
    // We are going to print this to the logfile
    if (log_level >= level) {
        va_start(args, format);
        ret = vfprintf(log_f, format, args);
        va_end(args);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

In the main function, I call the out_printf():

```
outlog_printf(1, "Initialize the program!\n");
```

I use g++ to compile the program, and it seems fine. But when I execute it, the error occurs:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

And then, I tried to debug it with gdb. When it comes to the following statement(which is in the outlog_printf function):

```
ret = vfprintf(log_f, format, args);
```

I get the following error:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   `___vfprintf_chk (fp=0x0, flag=1, format=0x8b59050 "Initialize the program!\n", 
>       ap=0xbfffee78 "\n")` at vfprintf_chk.c:29
>   29  vfprintf_chk.c: No such file or directory.

I have googled a lot, and find no solution...
BTW, I'm under Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: what is `log_f`? did you check it's validity?

Comment: I see the `static FILE* log_f = NULL;`, is that why problem occurs?

Comment: Yes, most probably. you cannot write (print) to a NULL file pointer, can you? :-)

Comment: The "No such file or directory" message happens because that's where the source for `vfprintf` is but gdb can't find it. If gdb had found it, it would have displayed line 29 of that file.